# (Continuously) Stream binary data on localhost

Tags: networking

I have a binary file on disk and I want to stream the binary file on my localhost on a specific port. Preferably forever just repeating the file contents.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `nc` command could be used to do that. For example this is how you would create a TCP connection on port 12345 and stream a file to that. The `-k` option will keep the socket open after a client connected:

```
nc -k -l 12345 < input_file
```